# How to cancel the subscription to a Reactive Stream in Vert.x

Tags: reactive-programming, vert.x

I'm using ReactiveStreams to publish SSE events in Vert.x:

```
ReactiveStreams.fromPublisher(vertx.periodicStream(1000).toPublisher())
        .map(l -> String.format("Number of Customer added %s .%n",
                customerRepository.findAll().size() + " "))
        .buildRs();
```

Is there any way to cancel the subscription to the streaming of data? 
Thanks

Comment: Can you update your question to be more precise? Do you want to know how to cancel a subscription in general? How to build a stream of ticks with a limit? Thanks

Comment: Thanks I've updated the source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `buildRs()` method returns a `Publisher`:

```
Publisher<String> publisher = ReactiveStreams.fromPublisher(vertx.periodicStream(1000).toPublisher())
  .map(l -> String.format("Number of Customer added %s .%n",
    customerRepository.findAll().size() + " "))
  .buildRs();
```

When you subscribe to this `Publisher` you can keep a reference to the `Subscription` and then cancel emission when you're done:

```
publisher
  .subscribe(new Subscriber<String>() {
    volatile Subscription subscription;

    @Override
    public void onSubscribe(Subscription subscription) {
      this.subscription = subscription;
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(String s) {
      // when no more event is needed
      subscription.cancel();
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
      // handle error
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete() {
      // handle complete
    }
  });
```